# .net core mvc API deployed on UBUNTU using NGINX reverse proxy, POST request throws 404 error

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, http-status-code-404, asp.net-core-webapi, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have created a .net core API, which is in turn being used inside a .net core web app. These are deployed on an ubuntu machine using its IP and custom ports. The service files for both the API and webapp have been pasted below. When ever I try to POST data through the web app, it gives an error "404", stating that the post function is nowhere to be found.

Both API and webApp are hosted through the IP, but when they are hosted using localhost, the POST request works fine. Which is not helpful as these are to be hosted through the IP itself.

Posting my files below, please help.

```
server {
listen      6002;
server_name attendanceapp;
root        /home/arun/net-core/Publish/AttendanceModule/AttendanceAPI;
location /attendancepp/{
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass      http://192.168.0.27:6002;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
            proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type';
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json';
    }
```

}

```
server {
listen      192.168.0.27:6001;
server_name attendancepi;
root        /home/arun/net-core/Publish/AttendanceModule/AttendanceAPI;
location /attendanceapi/ {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

}

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWlAc.png)

Comment: As far as I know, 404 means the page couldn't find. I suggest you could firstly check the asp.net core api has started and work well on the server. Then I suggest you could check you could access the server by using the ip address by using ping CMD method. Besides, I suggest you could try to follow below [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to know how to use nigix to host asp.net core application.

Comment: @BrandoZhang
There were not many changes to be made in my APP, API, NGINX service files as mentioned in the link. But while going through it,(links mentioned at the end in the link you provided) I found that there were some other configurations to be made. I have tried adding CORS in my API as well, but it did not help.
Also, as suggested by you, I tried a POST request from a different machine using the IP mentioned, even there POST method throws a 404 error for the page. Yet GET request works perfectly fine. I have tried adding headers as well with CORS, but no success to be found yet.

Comment: @BrandoZhang 
I have tried implementing CORS in both, API and APP, but even that did not help. Post request is still throwing strict-cross-origin issue.